# Flex Event.ID3 dispatches twice

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, dispatch

Why does this code

```
mySound.addEventListener(Event.ID3, myID3Handler);
```

cause the `myID3Handler` to run twice ?!

I also notice that values provided to the handler are not the same, actually the second being the correct one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most probably because the mp3 file that you are loading contains ID3 info in both versions: ID3v1 and ID3v2. You can check this with winamp or other mp3 player. You can also edit the file and delete one of the ID3 versions a try to load it again to see if the handler still get's called twice.